# Creating an upload queue

Tags: android, service, upload, android-intent

So I need to upload multiple images to a webserver. I have the upload method created. I now need a way to make an upload queue so that I can manage and cancel the uploads. What is the best way to do something like this? I will defenetly be running a service for this. I was looking over the IntentService class and it seems like a good way to do the queue (since I just need to upload 1 file at a time), but my uploading will consist of 3 parts- the first part I am calling a server to get authorization, the second will be the actual upload and the third will be sending a confirmation that the file was successfully sent.

Ok so here is the deal. How do I cancel a specific download in the queue? How do I postpone the destroying of the service if the process is in the third part of the upload (posting the successful upload info to a webService)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I cancel a specific download in the queue?

With `IntentService`, you don't. You would need to write your own `Service` that behaves like `IntentService` (background thread, work queue, `stopSelf()` when queue is empty), but where you can better manage the queue.

> How do I postpone the destroying of the service if the process is in the third part of the upload

If you are using `IntentService` or your own `IntentService`-workalike, the service will not normally be destroyed until there is no more work to be done.

If you are concerned over Android shutting down your service because it thinks you have been in memory too long, use `startForeground()`.

Comment: Ok. clear. is there any example that can help me of how i can create a service like you describe?

Comment: @DArkO: I don't have anything that quite matches.

Comment: ok. not a problem. you have been of great assistance so far in any case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From API 11 up, a good approach is to use a FixedThreadPool with async tasks. Do once:

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Where 3 is the number of downloads you want to run at the same time. It will queueu the task if there are already 3 downloads running, and automatically handle the task later. 
Launch your async tasks with:

```
yourAsynTask.executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor, params);
```

Params is probably the url you wish to connect to. You can read it out in the onPostExecute of your asynctask, and connect to the server using a [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Make sure you call down this on shutdown:

```
threadPoolExecutor.shutdown()
```